# AWS Connect - How to automate outbound call?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-connect

I am able to make manual calls to my customers. However, if I want to send an automated message to these customers the previous night, is it possible? What could be the possible steps:

1. The customer information can be stored in a DynamoDB table.
2. I can create a contact flow:  `Start, Call Phone no, Set Voice, Play Prompt, End flow`
3. If the flow is correct then which block will make the db/Lambda call? (Is it play prompt?)
4. I tried using `StartOutboundVoice` but if the contact flow is Outbound Whisper then it does not work.

Really appreciate some help.

Comment: Judi, does my reply answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: create a lambda to call the [StartOutboundVoiceContact](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/APIReference/API_StartOutboundVoiceContact.html) API action

Here are two guides from AWS which I found quite useful

- [Automating outbound calling to customers using Amazon Connect](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/contact-center/automating-outbound-calling-to-customers-using-amazon-connect)
- [Creating an outbound calling solution during a pandemic using Amazon Connect](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/publicsector/creating-outbound-calling-solution-pandemic-using-amazon-connect)

The authors go through a couple of use-cases which you may find relevant.